# PyQt5: Sending and receiving messages between client and server

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I am trying to create a server and client to send and receive messages. My problem is to send and receive between the client and the server.

*client.py*:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpSocket

class Client(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        HOST = '127.0.0.1'
        PORT = 8000
        self.tcpSocket = QTcpSocket(self)
        self.tcpSocket.connectToHost(HOST, PORT, QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        self.tcpSocket.readyRead.connect(self.dealCommunication)
        self.tcpSocket.error.connect(self.displayError)

    def dealCommunication(self):
        print("connected !\n")
        # i want here to send and receive messages

    def displayError(self):
        print(self, "The following error occurred: %s." % self.tcpSocket.errorString())

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = Client()
    sys.exit(client.exec_())
```

*server.py*:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QDataStream, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QHostAddress, QTcpServer, QTcpSocket

class Server(QDialog, QTcpSocket):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tcpServer = None

    def sessionOpened(self):
        self.tcpServer = QTcpServer(self)
        PORT = 8000
        address = QHostAddress('127.0.0.1')
        self.tcpServer.listen(address, PORT)
        self.tcpServer.newConnection.connect(self.dealCommunication)

    def dealCommunication(self):
        # i want here to send and receive messages 
        data = input()
        block = QByteArray()
        out = QDataStream(block, QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        out.writeQString(data)
        clientConnection = self.tcpServer.nextPendingConnection()
        clientConnection.write(block)
        clientConnection.disconnectFromHost()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    server = Server()
    server.sessionOpened()
    sys.exit(server.exec_())
```

I have searched but I am so confused. I found some code, but I can't understand what it does exactly:

```
data = input()
block = QByteArray()
out = QDataStream(block, QIODevice.ReadWrite)
out.writeQString(data)
clientConnection = self.tcpServer.nextPendingConnection()
clientConnection.write(block)
clientConnection.disconnectFromHost()
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: i want to send and receive text messages between client.py and server.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

client.py

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDataStream, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpSocket, QAbstractSocket

class Client(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tcpSocket = QTcpSocket(self)
        self.blockSize = 0
        self.makeRequest()
        self.tcpSocket.waitForConnected(1000)
        # send any message you like it could come from a widget text.
        self.tcpSocket.write(b'hello')
        self.tcpSocket.readyRead.connect(self.dealCommunication)
        self.tcpSocket.error.connect(self.displayError)

    def makeRequest(self):
        HOST = '127.0.0.1'
        PORT = 8000
        self.tcpSocket.connectToHost(HOST, PORT, QIODevice.ReadWrite)

    def dealCommunication(self):
        instr = QDataStream(self.tcpSocket)
        instr.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_0)
        if self.blockSize == 0:
            if self.tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() < 2:
                return
            self.blockSize = instr.readUInt16()
        if self.tcpSocket.bytesAvailable() < self.blockSize:
            return
        # Print response to terminal, we could use it anywhere else we wanted.
        print(str(instr.readString(), encoding='ascii'))

    def displayError(self, socketError):
        if socketError == QAbstractSocket.RemoteHostClosedError:
            pass
        else:
            print(self, "The following error occurred: %s." % self.tcpSocket.errorString())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    client = Client()
    sys.exit(client.exec_())
```

server.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QByteArray, QDataStream, QIODevice
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QHostAddress, QTcpServer

class Server(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.tcpServer = None

    def sessionOpened(self):
        self.tcpServer = QTcpServer(self)
        PORT = 8000
        address = QHostAddress('127.0.0.1')
        if not self.tcpServer.listen(address, PORT):
            print("cant listen!")
            self.close()
            return
        self.tcpServer.newConnection.connect(self.dealCommunication)

    def dealCommunication(self):
        # Get a QTcpSocket from the QTcpServer
        clientConnection = self.tcpServer.nextPendingConnection()
        # instantiate a QByteArray
        block = QByteArray()
        # QDataStream class provides serialization of binary data to a QIODevice
        out = QDataStream(block, QIODevice.ReadWrite)
        # We are using PyQt5 so set the QDataStream version accordingly.
        out.setVersion(QDataStream.Qt_5_0)
        out.writeUInt16(0)
        # this is the message we will send it could come from a widget.
        message = "Goodbye!"
        # get a byte array of the message encoded appropriately.
        message = bytes(message, encoding='ascii')
        # now use the QDataStream and write the byte array to it.
        out.writeString(message)
        out.device().seek(0)
        out.writeUInt16(block.size() - 2)
        # wait until the connection is ready to read
        clientConnection.waitForReadyRead()
        # read incomming data
        instr = clientConnection.readAll()
        # in this case we print to the terminal could update text of a widget if we wanted.
        print(str(instr, encoding='ascii'))
        # get the connection ready for clean up
        clientConnection.disconnected.connect(clientConnection.deleteLater)
        # now send the QByteArray.
        clientConnection.write(block)
        # now disconnect connection.
        clientConnection.disconnectFromHost()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    server = Server()
    server.sessionOpened()
    sys.exit(server.exec_())
```

It comes with very limited error handling but shows you the basics.

**Edited to explain the code you wanted explaining**

Comment: thanks  a lot. but what about making it like a chat not just a message ?

message = input()

Comment: It's beyond the scope of a question to implement a chat server. But for a start you can not push to the client with the code you have - the client connects sends a message and receives a message. If you had two instances of client you may be able to get them to chat via the server. You would need to add a QTextEdit QLabel and QPushButton and link the request code to the button and update the  QLabel with the response. Then you would need some sort of routing on the server to route one clients messages to the other on the next request. Then you would need to get the clients to poll the server.

Comment: But I think I answered your original question.

Comment: yeah, it was just a question. I marked it as an answer,Thanks a lot bro.